# How to open a PDF automatically from a DataFrame?

Tags: r

I have a dataFrame containing the names of `pdf`in a column. However, when I try to get the `a` field (containing the name of the files) of one row, I get sth like this : [image],

I would like to use `openFile` function to open directly the PDF with its name; here, sth like `openFile(g$a))`. However, when I do this, it doesn't work because `g$a`contains "dirt" (the index on the left, the unuseful line at the bottom coming from nowhere,...)

How can I just get the proper title to automatically put it as the `openFile`function argument and get rid of the dirt around ?

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried without the quotes, `openFile(g$a)`? Like this you are telling `openFile` to open a file named `g$a`, not `this_and_that.pdf`.

Comment: @RuiBarradas I edited my question, I actually proceeded without quotes, thanks for noticing it however

Comment: Try by converting to `character` i.e. `openFile(as.character(g$a))`

Comment: Is it a problem with factors? Maybe try `openFile(as.character(g$a))`.

Comment: @F.Privé Thanks it works !

Comment: @akrun Thanks it works !

Comment: I have just tried the suggestions by @akrun and @F.Privé and they are right, `as.character` works. Without it I got the error `Error in path.expand(path) : invalid 'path' argument`.